# XSD2CODE - Remove xsi:type tag from XML

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xsd, xsd2code

I'm serializing an object automatically created by Xsd2Code, the resulting XML has xsi:type tags under each of the xml values:

```
<shape xsi:type="xsd:int">1</shape>
```

I need to remove these and if doing that manually i would normally just change the namespace but here i want to do this with the Xsd2Code generator, does anyone know of which config needs to be changed to achieve this?

[image: Xsd2Code Config]

Comment: Presumably this happens because the XSD allows more than one type for shape?

Comment: No, just an xs:element in a sequence.

Comment: With what type? Can you include the XSD? Or the relevant parts of it?

Comment: You only get xsi:type if you have inherited classes.  Did Xsd2Code generate inherited classes?

Comment: Yes it did, any idea how to prevent this in the settings?

Comment: You can't inherit from an integer, so that isn't relevant. The property for shape will  have been generated as a property with the type `object`. And the reason for that will likely be clear from the XSD, and is likely correct.